# Error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 0 in React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, momentjs

react native fetching rejected with **Error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 0** when applying the moment-timezone module

i have used `MomentTimezone.tz(new Date().getTime(), 'America/New_York')` as the fetching request message value

Comment: is it working in other functions, or `momentTimezone` is not working at all?

Comment: Can you paste what's coming back? Did you check if it is actually a valid JSON?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan other fetching requests are working properly except requests which are use timezone data as the message. and also timezone casting working properly

Comment: @AshanJayasundara can you please add a block of code? and error stack?

Comment: `moment.tz.load(require('./data/packed/latest.json'));`
are you loading your timezone data?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan i am not loading timezone data JSON
`import MomentTimezone from 'moment-timezone';
 return MomentTimezone.tz(new Date().getTime(), 'America/New_York')
`

Answer (score 1):

You need to load timezone data first, before you parse timezone.
See the documentation at [Moment Timezone Data Loading](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/)

Also I think you want to send date instead of New York Time. Does your request actually requires That time can be used for display however if you have to send that time with your request (to a server) you need to convert your `moment` instance to `date` object like this

```js
const now = new Date();
const myMoment = momentTimezone.tz(now.getTime(), 'America/NewYork');
const dateForRequest = myMoment.toDate();
```

if you want new york time, you need to specify which time do you actually want.
Consider I want to know what will be the time( with respect to UTC or Epoch) when New York time will be `2017-12-1 03:30`.

```
const timeString = '2017-12-1 03:30'
const myMoment = momentTimezone.tz(timeString, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm', 'America/NewYork');
const dateForRequest = myMoment.toDate();
```

Comment: Actually i want to get system time in milliseconds with respect to **'America/New_York'** timezone.  but this is not works for me.
`MomentTimezone.tz(new Date().getTime(), 'America/New_York').toDate().getTime();`
this will return the local time in milliseconds

Comment: You might want to look at this: 
https://github.com/kdeldycke/awesome-falsehood#dates-and-time